# Responsive gallery component with auto adjusting images

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, gallery

I am working on a gallery layout which would have 4 columns. I would want all the images to fit inside the component automatically without their aspect ratio being changed. All images are to be populated from a DB and can have varying dimensions. Some specific images shall be occupying 2 columns and that is where my problem lies. Since all the images are dynamically put onto the front-end, how do I have those specific images to occupy 2 columns?
I am working on next JS with typescript.

I tried using the Masonry layout but in that I did not have control over the rows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Flex layout will do the job

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In addition to posting your code, please also post an image of what would you like to achieve, possibly the design or a mockup.